# Adding an array of recycleview with generate number when I click add button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I want to make alert dialog like this
[image: first picture]

After clicking the button "tebang", the screen will show an alert dialog like this
[image: after click button "tebang" screen will be show alert dialog like this]

After clicking the "+" button, an array of recycler view is added
[image: after click button "+" array of recycler view is added]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you cannot use the default view that comes with an alert dialogue, you can create your own layout of your desired design and then inflate it into your alert dialogue. The code will be something similar to this:

View yourCustomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
alertDialog.setView(yourCustomView);

The layout that's inflated will have the recycler view and all the other views of your requirement. This layout will contain the recycler view and when you press the button, you can just add the elements you want to the list. I hope this was helpful :)

Comment: oke, but how to show dynamic data like third picture?

Comment: By dynamic data, do you mean the text "0040L20AA" and "0040L20AB"?

Comment: No, i want to make this data can save in database using mvvm